# Migration to  Selenium 2 from Selenium1 :Unable to find any elements using XPath or CSS

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I am trying migrate to Selenium 2 (WebDriver) from Selenium 1 (rc).

I have replaced the below code with the Firefox driver upon which my browser opens and runs:

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(
    "localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.yoursite.com");
selenium.start();
```

My problem is that Selenium cannot find any elements using XPath or CSS, just id seem to work so far. I have tried using different XPath and css locators, as well as DOM, but they don't work. The Selenium migration guide said finding elements by XPath or CSS Selectors does not  always work but they don't  seem to work for me at all.

Below is an example of an element I am trying to identify along with the CSS identifier I am trying to use, which works in selenium 1 and in the Selenium IDE :

```
<div id="GUID_3" class="DA_COMPONENT DA_SPEEDBUTTON" style="line-height: 16px; cursor: default;" title="Actions">

css=[title='Actions']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try css=div[title='Actions'].  You need to specify an element to match the attribute on.  Or if you want any element, css=*[title='Actions']

Comment: Is it a requirement for Selenium CSS locators to specify a type or universal selector for attributes? `[title='Actions']` is valid CSS and will match the same thing as `*[title='Actions']`, so I see no reason it shouldn't work here unless it's a Selenium-specific thing.

Comment: I tried css=div[title='Actions'] in the ide and it worked but in the code it doesn't

Comment: It's a CSS Selector requirement to have an element.  Browsers tend to guess what you want, but staying strict gives you a better chance of working.  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Post the exact code that you are using the selector in, please.

Comment: @Nialscorva: Where does it say that it's a requirement to have a type or universal selector with an attribute selector?

Comment: @BoltClock my bad.  Section 5.3 explicitly says that you can omit the universal selector on attributes.  Sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [2.19](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/announcing-selenium-2-19-the-prancing-unicorn-release/), it supposedly makes the migration from 1.X to 2.X much easier.

Is there any reason you aren't searching on the ID?  It's much faster anyhow.